# Xamarin Grid: How to use corner radius in xamarin grid dynamically

Tags: c#, xamarin

```
for (int i = 0; i <= linhas.Length - 2; i++)
{
   string[] linha = linhas[i].Split(';');

   Grid grid = new Grid
   {
       RowSpacing = 1,
       BackgroundColor = Color.Beige,
       Margin = new Thickness(10, 10, 10, 5),
   };

   grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = 40 });
   grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = 60 });

   grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = 40 });
   grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });

   Label lbltitle = new Label
   {
       Text = linha[2],
       TextColor = Color.FromHex("#282643"),
       FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Large, typeof(Label)),
       HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
       VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
   };
   Label lbltex = new Label
   {
       Text = linha[3],
       TextColor = Color.FromHex("#282643"),
       FontSize = 18,
       HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
       VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
       Margin = new Thickness(5, 0, 0, 0)
   };
}
```

What I want is basically to be able to add a CornerRadius to the grid. 
The grid is created programmatically.
This is a list come to the api data.

I can't modify in xml, because the grid is created in c# file.

Comment: Grid doesn't have a CornerRadius property. Wrap it in a Frame.

Comment: how? I've tried, but I can't. can you help me?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/frame. The c# example that shows setting CornerRadius on a Frame. Then add your Grid as a child of that frame.